# SQLAlchemy Query not returning all of large text field

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlalchemy

First up, here's a little bit about my environment:

- Using MSSMS as my database management tool.
- Using Django 1.3
- Using SQLAlchemy

I have a text field in the database with no max length. There is text in it that is 890591 characters long.

When I retrieve this field using `SQLAlchemy` it is truncated to 64512 characters. I've tried it with several other large rows too, and it's always truncated to 64512.

`SELECT @@TEXTSIZE` returns some absurd value like 1.6 million, so that's not the problem. If I do `SELECT DATALENGTH(field)` it returns the correct 890591. So it doesn't seem to be the database, it seems to be `SQLAlchemy`. Or perhaps it could be some Python limit.

Any ideas? I seem to be at my wits end.

EDIT: Here's some more info that was requested:

OS: Debian 5.0.9

SQLAlchemy: 0.7.3

SQL: MS Sql Server 2008

DB Connection: mssql+pymssql://name:password@server/dbname

pymssql version: 1.0.2

Model in question:

```
class RACReport(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RACReport'
    id                      = Column(properUUID(), primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=genuuid4, server_default=text('NEWID()'))
    client_id               = Column(properUUID(), ForeignKey(Client.id), nullable=False)
    rawdata                 = Column(Text(), nullable=True)
    rawtime                 = Column(DateTime(), nullable=True, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    processeddata           = Column(Text(), nullable=True)
    processedtime           = Column(DateTime(), nullable=True)
    reportstartdate         = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False)
    reportenddata           = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False)
    numberofdocs            = Column(Integer(), nullable=True)
RACReport.__table__.schema='rac'

class properUUID(st.TypeDecorator):
    impl = mssql.MSUniqueIdentifier
    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value:
            return str(uuid.UUID(bytes_le=value))

def genuuid4():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())
```

rawdata and processdata are the two fields he is having the problem with.

Here's a test query and echo:

`rac.session.query(rac.RACReport).filter(rac.RACReport.id=='8fb76cb7-d752-45af-a20a-3b85d5e7b8a6').all()`

`2011-11-17 09:39:46,890 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT [RACReport_1].id AS [rac_RACReport_id], [RACReport_1].client_id AS [rac_RACReport_client_id], [RACReport_1].rawdata AS [rac_RACReport_rawdata], [RACReport_1].rawtime AS [rac_RACReport_rawtime], [RACReport_1].processeddata AS [rac_RACReport_processeddata], [RACReport_1].processedtime AS [rac_RACReport_processedtime], [RACReport_1].reportstartdate AS [rac_RACReport_reportstartdate], [RACReport_1].reportenddate AS [rac_RACReport_reportenddate]
FROM rac.[RACReport] AS [RACReport_1]
WHERE [RACReport_1].id = %(id_1)s
2011-11-17 09:39:46,890 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'id_1': '8fb76cb7-d752-45af-a20a-3b85d5e7b8a6'}`

Comment: Kinda interesting that the value is the same as 2^16 - 2^10.

Comment: @BrianCain I thought that too...

Comment: Can you single-step into the relevant `SQLAlchemy` code with `pdb` or `pudb`?

Comment: @BrianCain Hmmm...it's breaking for me when I run it in pdb because it can't find a variable, so I think pdb might be taking it out of scope or something. I'm new to iPython though, so I'll have my coworker take a look at it with pdb tomorrow. He couldn't come up with a solution to the problem today either, so I've just been researching it since he left the office.

Comment: Would you mind posting your model definition for the object/field in question as well as the DB connection setting specifically driver used, as well as OS, versions of the SA and SQL Server.

Comment: Could the 1.6 million figure be double the actual length?  If so that could be the byte-length of the text in UTF-16.  Also, in addition to the info @van requested please pass `echo=True` to `create_engine` and post the SQL.

Comment: Please send an email to sqlalchemy mailinglist or post it in issue tracker.

Comment: @van: My coworker posted all the information requested as an answer below.

Comment: @wberry I edited the answer below to include the echo=True SQL, but it has to be peer reviewed.

Comment: re echoed query: do you still see the bad data by executing this query manually?  You can try `session.execute()`, `pymssql.cursor().execute()` and from the MSSQL console.  it would probably help to isolate where the data is being corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know little of *nix connectivity to SQL Server, but simple googling suggests that the issue is related to [FreeTDS](http://freetds.schemamania.org/index.html) configuration:

1. A related question on SO: [Data ended at 64512 characters - MSSQL // PHP // OPENSuSE // APACHE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635036/data-ended-at-64512-characters-mssql-php-opensuse-apache2).
2. Another Q&A extracted from [here](http://freetds.schemamania.org/faq.html#textdata):

> My text data are being truncated or are causing my client to break.
>
> The text data type is different from char and varchar types. The
>   maximum data length of a text column is governed by the textsize
>   connection option. Microsoft claims in their documentation to use a
>   default textsize of 4000 characters, but in fact their implementation
>   is inconsistent. Sometimes text columns are returned with a size of 4
>   GB!
>
> The best solution is to make sure you set the textsize option to a
>   reasonable value when establishing a connection. For example:

```
1> set textsize 10000 
2> go
```

> See also the text size option in freetds.conf.

---

And just a side note: you seem to be using rather outdated version of [`pymssql`](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/).

Comment: The freetds.conf sets the text size to 64512 by default, for whatever reason. Remove the text size limit from the config file and the library (according to documentation) should default to some really huge size.

Comment: Changing the freetds.conf worked, thanks guys! I was unaware that freeTDS was the backend for pymssql.